# how to redirect to a visualforce page from sforce.navigatetourl?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

Below is my code to launch a vf page from another page in salesforce1 mobile app. But this is not working, could some one help if there is any error with the code?

```
   if(sforce.one){
   sforce.one.navigateToURL("/apex/testInfo");
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: `if(sforce.one)[` should be `if(sforce.one){`, won't compile like this.

Comment: have corrected it, it was a typo

Comment: what error are you getting?